# Store a method's name in a variable and call that method using that variable

Tags: java

I want to call a method whose name (with or without parentheses and parameters) is stored in a string variable and call this method using this variable.

Until now I have found that in Java if you do this:

```
String str = "func();";
System.out.println(str);
```

This would call method `func()`. But I don't think this is recommended.
So, my question is:

1. Is it okay to do this?
2. Is there any other way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Reflection API could help you :)

Comment: Your example will simply print out a String that says `func();`. There's no method name `func()` being called. It's possible to to achieve that with reflection, but almost always there's a cleaner way to do it. Why do you think you need to invoke methods inside Strings?

Comment: That would not call method `func()`. That would just println func();

Answer (score 1):

```
Method m = YourClass.class.getMethod("methodName", parametersOfYourMethods);
```